# Does an antonym of ''freezing'' as a descriptor of weather exist?

Tags: antonyms

On very cold days, someone can say that it's freezing outside. On very hot days of summer, can someone use *cooking* or any antonym of *freezing*, if one exists?

Comment: Have you looked up antonyms of _freezing_? Have a look [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/freezing) (Merriam-Webster.com, always a good start in research) and let us know whether something sounds right, or what sounds "off" about the choices they give. After that, we'll be able to help. Without that, it's possible your question might be closed for "General Reference".

Comment: Ultrahot seems good to me, so you can close this topic.

Comment: And there you go! I know we have a list of what counts as "General Reference" for the site; I can never remember where it is kept. I'm sure someone can come along and post it, but you can also look around yourself. Checking the General Reference for information is **always** good; it helps us give you a better answer (and makes things a bit more fun and interesting for us :-) ).

Comment: And @Archa, by the way, before we close the question you should post "ultrahot" as your own answer. Maybe even tell us a bit about why you like the term.

Comment: *Baking*, *broiling*, *burning*, *scorching*, *cooking*, anything that connotes being cooked, heated, or burned.

Comment: If it's *only* freezing outside that's a fairly warm day.

Answer (score 57):

It's both a British and US colloquialism to use 'boiling'.

Also referenced here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boiling

Answer (score 56):

I've also heard [*scorching*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scorching) used; it seems to describe the condition of the pavement quite well.

Comment: That was the first word that popped into my mind as well.

Comment: I see this in writing a lot and it's a common word but I've never (or maybe very rarely) used it or heard it in casual conversation - it might depend on location, though.

Answer (score 37):

While 'boiling' is a commonly used option, my suggestion would be 'sweltering', as it removes any possible ambiguity.

[Sweltering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweltering)

Answer (score 18):

I'm from Arizona where the weather is scorching and the people are roasting.

It's freezing outside.
It's scorching outside.

I'm freezing.
I'm roasting.

Comment: Dude. You need to see a doctor.

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned *blistering* yet, which refers to intense heat.

Answer (score 6):

As no-one else has addressed this specific point: *Cooking* is used in this sense in Australia at least.

*Cooking* seems to capture the feel of being in an oven in such conditions. I personally would probably only use it in temperatures well above blood heat.

With regards to the other words suggested:

*Boiling* and *scorching* are common in the UK. I vaguely recall a tabloid headline 'What a scorcher'.

It seems to me that *boiling* is hyperbole, as others have noted.

*Scorching* is however literally true, just like *freezing* can be.

*Freezing* is also used in the UK and especially Australia in a non-literal sense.

*Torrid* is of course also correct provided it is a dry heat. I don't hear spoken much (anyone differ?), but it is definitely written use.

*Sweltering* is valid if there is humidity, and in common use in verbal and written forms.

Comment: RE: The tabloid headline for some reason it has become some sort of ironic tradition for newspapers to use the headline "phew! What a scorcher" on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

*Doubleplus uncold*

On topic: I've heard of "it's *burning hot* outside" before

Comment: My +1 for 1984.

Comment: More appropriate for newspeak.stackexchange

Answer (score 4):

"Baking" would be the closest term usable as per it's definition.

Answer (score 2):

Don't disregard "hot" just because of its simplicity.

The other answers here are good; particularly "boiling", "blistering", and "scorching", but I feel that most of the words here are used more in descriptive writing than in casual conversation (based on personal experience; not concrete evidence).

If I were to start up small talk with, for example, a person waiting at a bus stop, or if I were to walk outside and comment on the weather to my neighbor, I would generally say:

- Cold: It is *freezing* out here!
- Hot: It is *hot* out here! (I know this is boring and perhaps obvious, but emphasis on "hot" will convey the intensity as much as "freezing" does.)
- Hot: It is *hot as Hell* out here!
- Hot: Damn, it's *hot*!

You can use analogies, such as:

- It's like an oven out here today!

You can add intensity with incredulity, e.g.

- I can't believe how hot it is!

You can also qualify "hot" with an adverb to increase intensity:

- It is *incredibly hot* out today!
- It is *insanely hot* out today! (colloquialism)
- It is *ridiculously hot* out today!

Or if it's already understood that it is hot (e.g. the person you are speaking to is outside with you, perhaps sweating), things as simple as:

- Can you believe this?
- Where did this come from?
- Wow!
- It's crazy out there! (esp. if you say this upon walking indoors, sweating)

If indoors or in a cooler space you can also use the contrast with the cooler environment to convey the heat, for example:

- Thank God for air conditioning!
- Wow, it feels good to get out of that heat.
- I'm not leaving this room until winter! (when in a cool room on a hot day)

However, when *writing*, where more poignant words are more commonplace than in spoken conversation; words like *burning*, *scorching*, *boiling*, etc. are very good.

In general, nearly any word or phrase that brings one of the following to mind will be understood as conveying intense heat:

- Fire
- Hell
- Cooking
- Melting / Boiling / anything else that is a consequence of high heat (e.g. "blistering", "scorching", etc.)

The word "hot" itself does go a long way on its own, though, and shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: This would have been an OK answer if you had stopped after the second paragraph.

Comment: @MrLister What's the issue with the rest? I want to remove or edit if it is bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

How about “[torrid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/torrid)”?

Comment: That depends on the climate. Our summers are humid, so torrid is not correct (definition of Merriam-Webster: _very hot and usually dry_).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard "I'm melting" used before. It has the advantage of being a literal opposite to freezing in addition to being a figurative opposite.

Comment: You might say "I'm melting", you would never say "It's melting outside".

Comment: The literal opposite to _freezing_ would be _thawing_. But that's not what the OP meant. Edit: Oh, I see this is already being covered in other comments.

Comment: @MrLister would you please explain what the difference between thawing and melting is?

Comment: @boileau Freezing and thawing imply a certain temperature - the melting point of water (zero °C). Other materials can be melting and solidifying at other temperatures (e.g. iron melts at 1538 °C), and you don't say of those materials that they're freezing or thawing at those temperatures.

Comment: @boileau "Freeze" is used to mean either "a liquid turning to a solid" (like when you make ice cubes) or "the water in something turning to ice" (like when you put chicken in the freezer). "Melting" is the opposite of the first sense; "thawing" of the second.

Comment: @MrLister No, not at all. Freezing for any particular substance implies a particular temperature: water does it at 0C, alcohol (ethanol) at -114C and so on. We don't normally talk about iron "freezing" simply because it's already a solid at temperatures that are normal to us. But the saying that iron melts at 1538C is exactly the same as saying that (molten) iron freezes at 1538C. And see my comment to boileau for the distinction between melting and thawing.

Answer (score 1):

*Sweltering* is a good antonym and is more related to weather than *boiling* is.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of two members, I answer my own question.

*boiling* and *ultrahot* seem to be correct.

Comment: Sweltering is better.

Comment: For me, *sweltering* implies humidity as well.

Comment: @Jim Not for me, though; I'm from the temperate part of Australia, and I can say from personal experience that the weather can be sweltering even when dry. I'm guessing the exact meaning differs slightly by region and dialect.

Comment: I'm from Arizona - it was 112 F the other day, (44.4 C) "It's a dry heat" is the mantra down here.  I just never consider it to be sweltering, unlike when I visit Houston where, because of the humidity, the heat, while not nearly as hot, is truly oppressive.

Comment: I have never heard the weather described as "ultrahot".

Comment: "Ultrahot" is a new one to me. "Roasting", "Sweltering", "Scorching", and "Boiling" are all more common to me.

Comment: Ultrahot is about the worst attempt in this whole thread, you might as well say it's _flippin' mega-hot_ - Certainly fine if you're Sue Townsend.

Comment: I hadn't even come across 'ultrahot' as a word before this thread.